# Regexp adds invisible dot character replacing \b

Tags: javascript, regex

I want this to be my regex: `/^word\b/` (`word` is dynamic)

When I set it up to be dynamic I have to use this:

```
var word='spoon';
'spoon .table .chair'.match(new RegExp('^'+word+'\b'));
```

However, this finds `null`, while this:

```
var word='spoon';
'spoon .table .chair'.match(/^spoon\b/);
```

finds `["spoon"]`.

The interesting part is when I examine the difference between the regex I worte and the regex RegExp wrote:

```
console.log(/^spoon\b/,new RegExp('^'+word+'\b'))
```

It shows this:

```
/^spoon\b/ /^spoon/
```

If I then copy the second part of the log output (`/^spoon/`) into my code editor I see this character:

[image: Looks like a dot.]

What is that? How do I do RegExp word-ending-with as I am not always guaranteed to have a space at the end when the string might be a one-word string (spoon or another word)

I'd rather just do this without the invisible thing

Comment: `'spoon .table .chair'.match(new RegExp('^'+word+'\\b'));` add modifier m if necessary ``'spoon .table .chair'.match(new RegExp('^'+word+'\\b', 'm'));``

Comment: asked and answered n number of times.

Comment: where I don't see, I wouldn't have asked otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, `\b` doesn't mean a `\` followed by a `b`. It means the backspace character (ASCII code 8). To get a `\` followed by a `b`, you need to escape the slash so that Javascript doesn't parse it as a backspace:

```
'^' + word + '\\b'
```

The same thing applies if you want to use `\d` or `\s` or anything else: You need to escape the `\` with another one so that Javascript doesn't think it's a Javascript escape code and the RegExp can parse it as what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You've got to escape the `\` in the `b` in the regex string by adding an extra slash:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^' + word + '\\b')
```

This is because the `RegExp` is expecting to see the two characters `\` and `b`, but the string `'\b'` is one character, ascii 8, the backspace character (in the same way that `'\n'` is a single newline character).